# Should I trim the fronds on a Queen palm?

Tags: pruning, palm

The fronds are very sturdy and bend almost to the ground. They are probably over 10ft. in length. Should I trim them? Their weight sometimes causes them to "crack" off.

Comment: Can you add a photograph please?

Comment: That is the natural growth pattern. Trimming does not hurt them.

Comment: Welcome! Would you please post a picture or two of your palm? Also, how old is it? Is it the lowest fronds, upper, or both, that are doing this?  We'd love some more details. You can [edit] them into your question rather than answering in comments. That way, all the information is in the same place for everyone to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Queen palms, and most palms, are being over-pruned in south Florida. The basic rule of thumb: if it is green it is helping tree grow and leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

A Queen Palm?  Yes, whenever any branch of a plant in the landscape grows so long it starts to bend the entire branch frond down to a point the weight (physics and levers) breaks the entire branch cutting that weight back where the frond bounces back up to relieve the pressure, is fine.  Not pretty, not normally necessary but the alternative is breaking the entire branch/frond.  Cut at an angle, clip a few leaflets (?) back  so it doesn't look lopped off and unnatural. Tough to do.

I'd look up some well paid landscaper that works on residential or commercial landscapes in your area and ask them what it is they do.  Ask for an example to go look at.  Start out by mentioning you are looking to hire a maintenance company then talk about this palm. Otherwise, they'll think you are competition or a DYI and they'll have nothing to do with you.  A Queen Palm?

You do have to send pictures before any pruning.  This plant is special, one of the most architectural plants in the world.  Please, we are dying to see this palm.  How old is it and where do you live?